# Sum HashMap, ArrayList values (from CSV)

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I'm trying to make a java program where I first read the lines from csv file then add the second column to hashmap and the third column is the value.

There are duplicate product_id's (second column) in the file  which have different values so I have added the values to array list. 
Now i have to figure out how to actually sum these values from arraylist and then write the output to csv file (new).

Input CSV (just the beginning of file):

```
466152;Product_69105;1
466152;Product_69133;6
466152;Product_69214;2
466152;Product_69216;2
466154;Product_01007;1
466154;Product_01083;1
466154;Product_01136;1
466154;Product_01155;1
466154;Product_01488;1
466154;Product_01491;1
466154;Product_01499;2
466154;Product_01513;1
466154;Product_01593;1
466154;Product_01646;1
466154;Product_01656;1
466154;Product_01688;1
466154;Product_01703;1
466154;Product_01770;1
466154;Product_01804;1
466154;Product_01909;1
```

.....

My output now:

```
Product_03067 [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
Product_82332 [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
Product_69594 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
Product_82330 [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
Product_03618 [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

....

Wanted output:

```
Product_03067, 20
Product_82332, 29
Product_69594, 12
Product_82330, 7
```

.....

```
Public class Tilausmäärä {

Map<String, List<Integer>> tuotteet;
String Tilausrivit = "tilausrivit.csv";
String Tilausrivit_2 = "abc.csv";

public Tilausmäärä() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    tuotteet = new HashMap<>();
    readTilausrivitFile();
}

  public void readTilausrivitFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Tilausrivit));
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String columns[] = line.split(";");
        String key = columns[1];
        int valueInt;
        List<Integer> valueList = null;

        try {
            valueInt = Integer.parseInt(columns[2]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            continue;
        }

        if (tuotteet.containsKey(key)) {
            valueList = tuotteet.get(key);
        } else {
            valueList = new ArrayList<>();
            tuotteet.put(key, valueList );    
        }
        valueList.add(valueInt);

    } 

    in.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Tilausmäärä tm = new Tilausmäärä();
        for (String k : tm.tuotteet.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(k + " " + tm.tuotteet.get(k));
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Could use some help so any good ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If the goal is to sum the values, why do you put them in a list, rather than sum them directly, when putting them in the map? Anyway, you seem to know how to build a map, I am pretty sure you can iterate on entries of a map (or at least, you should be able to figure that out by reading the documentation), and you should also be able to sum the elements of a list. Combine these three things, and you have your solution.

Comment: What kind of output are you trying to do? Another CSV file or just a terminal print?

Comment: The output should also be another csv file.

Comment: I edited my answer adding the code you are looking for. You can put Integers in a map

Comment: I'm still struggling a bit with the write output to csv file part.  Should I use BufferedWriter or what's the most efficient way to write the output to csv ? Any examples appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> There are duplicate product_id's (second column) in the file which
>   have different values so I have added the values to array list.

You could direct sum the values with the same product id.
The lists you are using don't seem required.

Your `tuotteet` map that is probably declared as `Map<String, List<Integer>>` could be `Map<String, Integer>` where the Integer value would be the sum.

The actual code where you populate the ArrayList :

```
 if (tuotteet.containsKey(key)) {
     valueList = tuotteet.get(key);
 } else {
     valueList = new ArrayList<>();
     tuotteet.put(key, valueList );    
 }
 valueList.add(valueInt);
```

could be :

```
  Integer actualValue = tuotteet.get(key);
  if (actualValue == null){
      tuotteet.put(key, valueInt);    
  }    
  else {
      tuotteet.put(key, actualValue + valueInt);    
  }
```

Comment: Seems like that is working! Actually should have left the list out straight away. Thanks for the excellent hint!   Now I have have to figure out how to write the output to a new csv file.

Comment: We do often things more complicated than required.You are welcome and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your code (a part of it is missing), you should have the total number as a value in the tuotteet map (whose definition is missing from the code you posted) and not the list. If the element is already in the map, you should increment its value, otherwise you should set its value to the current value.

Something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> tuotteet;
...
    try {
        valueInt = Integer.parseInt(columns[2]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        continue;
    }

    Integer val = null;
    if (tuotteet.containsKey(key)) {
        val = tuotteet.get(key) + valueInt;
    } else {
        val = valueInt;
    }
    tuotteet.put(key, val );
```